# make svg object clickable link and maintain the objects hover styles

Tags: css, svg

**The Problem**

I have an object for my SVG which is wrapped in an anchor. The problem I face is that I want my SVG to have hover styles but I also need it to be clickable, hence the need for the anchor.

**My Object:**

```
<a href="http://mylink.co.uk">
    <object data="mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <span>Your browser doesn't support SVG images</span>
    </object>
</a>
```

The problem is that the object is an element that has interaction and upon hover it was not registering the anchor. To combat this I tried:

```
object{
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

This solved that issue and let the be the clickable element. The downside is now my objects hover styles don't work because technically the object is not longer the element I'm hovering.

**Before the object...**

I originally adopted the method of using the xlink method:

```
<a href="#" class="my-button">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 297 149" class="my-icon">
     <use xlink:href="svgsprite.svg#my-icon"></use>
  </svg>
</a>
```

But I faced real issues getting the SVG parts to style consistently across browsers. Chrome in particular didn't like it.

Is there a way I can get the indivdual parts of my SVG styled via CSS, i.e. the fill colours and still use it in the way I'm trying to do by wrapping it within an anchor? Is there a newer (better) approach?

**You can find a working example to demonstrate my problem a little better. Please [find that here](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/JdpbZL).**

Comment: CSS styles do not apply across document boundaries.  Any CSS that's in your HTML will not be able to affect elements in the external SVG.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do (a test case would be useful).

But have you tried the approach of using an SVG `<a>` element, rather than an HTML one?  Perhaps that will help you avoid the issues you are having.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 297 149" class="my-icon">
  <a xlink:href="http://mylink.co.uk" class="my-button">
    <use xlink:href="svgsprite.svg#my-icon"></use>
  </a>
</svg>
```

SVG inherits some styling properties from external `<a>` elements in slightly unexpected ways. That may be the source of your styling woes.

Comment: I'll try make an example to demonstrate the problem better